# How to set the column name in the query UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql, union-all

I'm trying to query the database to get the three columns

```
(SELECT  SUM(result_enum) AS Positive FROM result WHERE result_enum > 0) 
  UNION ALL 
(SELECT  SUM(result_enum) AS Negative FROM result WHERE result_enum < 0) 
  UNION ALL
(SELECT  SUM(result_enum) AS Neutral FROM result WHERE result_enum  = 0)
```

but get the result in one column:

[image]

How to make a request to the database. If It not possible, Can I be sure that the result of the query will be in the same order in which I asked him in the request?

Thanks!

Comment: does it really matter that it's a 3x1 instead of a 1x3 ??

Comment: The last select could be simplified to "SELECT 0" as the result of summing all values equal to 0 will always be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single column this is not possible,you need three separate columns for each type

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN result_enum > 0 THEN result_enum ELSE 0 END) AS Positive,
        SUM(CASE WHEN result_enum < 0 THEN result_enum ELSE 0 END) AS Negative, 
        0 AS Neutral 
FROM TableName
```

Comment: The last sum is not required - it will always be zero.

Comment: @PaulF I have simplified the query to show the problem that I encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You're really looking to *group* summations of the `result_enum` column according to its [sign](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_sign):

```
SELECT SIGN(result_enum), SUM(result_enum) FROM result GROUP BY 1
```

This will yield:

```
+-------------------+------------------+
| SIGN(result_enum) | SUM(result_enum) |
+-------------------+------------------+
|                -1 |               -3 |  -- sign of -1 => "Negative"
|                 0 |                0 |  -- sign of  0 => "Neutral"
|                 1 |                9 |  -- sign of +1 => "Positive"
+-------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I have simplified the query to show the problem that encountered

Comment: @Roman:  Where have you done that?   You've not edited your question.

Comment: @Roman: Oh, I see.  Your question is already a simplification?  In that case, how is this answer inapplicable to your real problem?